# BoxLayout not showing all components

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, boxlayout

I am not sure how to fix this, I have several JPanels (used for drawing) inside a main JPanel using BoxLayout. The JPanels have a set minimum size and preferred size. The main JPanel only shows the 3 out of the five, as it is too small. I tried setting the size of the main JPanel pretty large and also tried adding a scroler but then nothing shows up.

Here is some code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws XMLStreamException, IOException {
    JFrame frame = makeFrame(500, 500);
    JPanel panel = new JPanel();
    panel.setSize(1800, 1800);
    JScrollPane scroller = new JScrollPane(panel);  

    panel.setLayout(new BoxLayout(panel, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));


    frame.add(scroller);

    test1(panel);

}
public static JFrame makeFrame(int sizex, int sizey){

    JFrame frame = new JFrame();

    frame.setTitle("FDA");
    frame.setSize(sizex, sizey);
    frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    frame.setVisible(true);
    return frame;
}
```

`test1` adds six JPanels with size 360x360 to `panel`.

With the scrollbar I only see one of the JPanels, and no scrollbars appear.

Edit: I have to wait until all my calculations are done before I paint the main JPanel, that is why it wasn't displaying the last 3.

Comment: Can we have a look at what you've tried (e.g the code)?

Comment: @Kezz101 I just posted some.

Comment: The code you posted doesn't help. Post a SSCCE.

Comment: @mihajlv What does `makeFrame` do? Do you pack the frame? The whole code would help greatly.

Comment: Still waiting on your [sscce](http://sscce.org) (please check on link). 1+ to mKorbel's answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- `frame.setVisible(true);` is executed before its `JComponents` are created and added (to this already visible JFrame)
- please whats `test1(panel);`